# Change default highlighted segment in morris.js

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I am using morris.js for donuts chart. I am done with all requirements except the following.

One segment is highlighted by default on load of page. How can I target that and highlight other segment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `select` method as described in [Morris documentation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html):

> Note: by default, the segment with the greatest value will be initially selected. You can change the selection using the `select(index)` method on the object returned by Morris.Donut.

Try this snippet to see a working example:

```js
var morrisDonut = Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut',
  data: [
    {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
    {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
    {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ],
  resize: true
});

morrisDonut.select(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="donut"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, can you tell how can we increase size of the segments, and remove inner line of the donut

Comment: Try to add this in your CSS: `path { stroke-width:0 }`. Please upvote my answer too if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you.. I dont knw how to upvote..I rarely used stack till now.. I just voted again by clicking your answer again.. is it done?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you needed 15 of reputation to upvote.